# Making two divs with different sizes visible on the screen all the time

Tags: html, css

I know, title might looks unclear, but I will try to explain what problem do I have. I have 2 divs, one high and one quite small in comparisson with the first one. First one is going to take 100% of the site's width so it's going to be visible the whole time. The thing is I want to see the 2. one. I want it to be kinda sticky. Here are pictures that I've made with my impressive skills :)
Those are situations that I want to achieve:
[image]

And this is situation I want to avoid:
[image]

If my goal is still unclear just let me know :)

Edit:
Here's demo of my code: 
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sv5hff27/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 long">
  long
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 short">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 shortLeft">
      short left
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 shortRight"> 
      short right
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.long{
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
.shortLeft{
  background-color: green;
  height:50px;
}
.shortRight{
  background-color: blue;
  height:50px;
}
.short{
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

Let's say your screen height is 75px. On wide screen position fixed works because 50px is less than 75 so you can see whole content. But with narrow screen you loose some content - position fixed is not the solution :(

Comment: I have updated my answer code to use max height and fix the short div height check on small and large size if this is what you wanted. This way the fixed position works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to apply position:fixed to the short div or the green div so that it always stays in front when you scroll. From what i understood, i made a sample to show you how position:fixed works. You can make changes in the div's class to change to what you want if i did not define the dimensions properly. Run the snippet to check.

```css
body {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color:yellow;
  margin:0px; 
  padding:0px;
}

.short {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width:74%; /*removed 1% due to the border widths*/
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  background-color:gray;
  max-height:150px; /*fix the height of the short div so that it does to extend in height on small screens*/
  overflow:auto; /*to have scroll in the short div content if height of the content exceeds the max height*/
}

.long {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width:25%;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="short">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="long">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</body>
```

**[EDIT]**

I have updated the code. Check now. You have to fix the height of the short div and make it's content to scroll if it exceeds that height. that way the div remains fixed while able to scroll the content in and it does not hide the other page items on small screens. Hope this helps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not what OP requests, OP wishes to have it scroll to the bottom, and then stick it there.

Comment: That works, but I already tried it. The thing is it works on big screen when short div is small enough to fit on the screen. But while shrinking it becomes thinner and longer and at some point he's higher that screen size. Then position: fixed hides some content. Also tried removing fixed from it when the screen is smaller than "x" pixels but that makes him disappear sometimes (image number 3)

Comment: Can you please post your code using codepen or jsfiddle for us to see what is happening? Actually your above comment has now confused me to what you actually want. Please update the question in detail as to what your wanting as screen size was not in the question you asked first.

Comment: I will prepare some demo for you :)

Comment: I have updated the code to use max height and fix the short div height check on small and large size if this is what you wanted.